# Rails. Cambiar opciones de un select cuando se selecciona un radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

tengo el siguiente código en un form for de view:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
  <%= f.label :Competition_type %> <br>
  <%= f.radio_button :type_competition, :value => "regression", :checked => true, id: "type_regression" %>
  <%= f.label :type_competition, "Regression"%>
  &nbsp;
  <%= f.radio_button :type_competition, :value => "classification", id: "type_classification" %>
  <%= f.label :type_competition, "Classification"%>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
  <%= f.label :Performance_metric %>
  <%= f.select(:metric, options_for_select([['Mean Absolute Error'],['Root Mean Squared Error'], ['Weighted Mean Absolute Error'], ['Accuracy'],['Mean Utility']]), {}, {class: "form-control", id: "selectMetric"}) %>
</div>
```

Alguien me echar una mano para hacer una función JavaScript que cuando se marque el radio button "regression", en el select solo aparezcan ['Mean Absolute Error'],['Root Mean Squared Error'],
['Weighted Mean Absolute Error'], y cuando se marque el radio button "classification" solo aparezcan ['Accuracy'],['Mean Utility'].

**Código generado**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label for="competition_Competition_type">Competition type</label> <br>
    <input class="my_radio" type="radio" value="regression" checked="checked" name="competition[type_competition]" id="competition_type_competition_regression" />
    <label for="competition_type_competition">Regression</label>
    &nbsp;
    <input class="my_radio" type="radio" value="classification" name="competition[type_competition]" id="competition_type_competition_classification" />
    <label for="competition_type_competition">Classification</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label for="competition_Performance_metric">Performance metric</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectMetric" name="competition[metric]">
       <option value="Mean Absolute Error">Mean Absolute Error</option>
       <option value="Root Mean Squared Error">Root Mean Squared Error</option>
       <option value="Weighted Mean Absolute Error">Weighted Mean Absolute Error</option>
       <option value="Accuracy">Accuracy</option>
       <option value="Mean Utility">Mean Utility</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Se lo agradeceré enormemente, ya que estoy bastante atascado en esto, no encuentro la info suficiente y necesito continuar

Muchas gracias a quien responda :)

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código generado en lugar del código en Ruby?

Comment: Si claro, actualizo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograrlo primero necesitas hacer un par de ajustes en tus `radio_button`:

1. Quita la llave `value` (esta se asigna directamente en el segundo argumento, así que únicamente deja el valor).
2. Agrega una clase (i.e. `class`) para poder identificar cuando se de clic a cualquiera de los dos `radio_button`.
3. Elimina la llave `id` por completo (esta se genera de manera automática utilizando el nombre y el valor del elemento).

Considerando lo anterior, así deberían verse tus elementos `radio_button`:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
  <%= f.label :Competition_type %> <br>
  <%= f.radio_button :type_competition, "regression", checked: true, class: "my-radio" %>
  <%= f.label :type_competition, "Regression"%>
  &nbsp;
  <%= f.radio_button :type_competition, "classification", class: "my-radio" %>
  <%= f.label :type_competition, "Classification"%>
</div>
```

Y utiliza el siguiente `script` para actualizar las opciones del `select`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.my-radio').change(function() {

      if($(this).val() == "regression") {
        var options = {
          'Mean Absolute Error': 'mean_absolute_error',
          'Root Mean Squared Error': 'root_mean_squared_error',
          'Weighted Mean Absolute Error': 'weighted_mean_absolute_error'
        };
      } else {
        var options = {
          'Accuracy': 'accuracy',
          'Mean Utility': 'mean_utility'
        };
      }

      $('#selectMetric').empty();
      $.each(options, function(key, value) {
        $('#selectMetric').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + key + '</option>');
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

El `script` hace lo siguiente:

- Detecta cuando el usuario da clic a cualquiera de los dos `radio_button` y ejecuta la función.
- Valida si `radio_button` al que dio clic tiene como valor `'regression'`, o tiene otro valor, y asigna las correspondientes (en forma de `hash`) en la variable `opciones`.
- Elimina las opciones del elemento `select`.
- Itera la variable `opciones` para agregar cada opción en el elemento `select`.

Comment: Muchas gracias Gerry por tu grandísima explicación. Pero no me funciona y no encuentro explicación por qué. El código javascript puede ir en mi view perfectamente no? Al final del código

Comment: @JorgeVelaPlaza Sí, el `script` ponlo en la misma vista. ¿Te muestra algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Nada... El f.select debe seguir igual que en mi código no? o lo debo dejar vacío

Comment: @JorgeVelaPlaza El `select` no necesita cambiar. ¿Tampoco te muestra un error en la consola del servidor?

Comment: Nada, y no sé porqué....todo parece estar correcto. El `select` ni se inmuta cuando marco un radio button, siguen las mismas 5 opciones

Comment: encontré el fallo: has de cambiar en el `script` lo siguiente: `$('.my-radio')` por `$('.my_radio')` . Puto guión jajaja. Muchas gracias de verdad!!!!!